# How to calculate the limit of the following sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We have sequence $a_n$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_na_{n+1} =1$, And $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_na_{n+2} =1$.

I need to show $a_n$ Converge and calculate its limit.

I tried to make an equaltions using the info provided, But It did not got me anywhere.
I don't see any information which may allow me to use any of the theorems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_na_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_na_{n+2}=1$ and $a_n>0$ find $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645025/if-lim-n-to-inftya-na-n1-lim-n-to-inftya-na-n2-1-and-a-n0-find)

Comment: There are two possible limits: $+1$ and $-1$. Are you sure the question didn't state that the $a_n$ are positive?

Comment: @MartinR Yes. Sorry for the duplication - I already searched around and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7Da_na_%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%3D1%24%2C%20AND%20content%3A%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7Da_na_%7Bn%2B2%7D%20%3D1%24) – see also [How to search on this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969)

Comment: @MartinR I will use it next time, Thanks!

Comment: @MartinR Not exactly a duplicate since $a_n >0$ is not given.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Yes, I had noticed that later. But the *question author* accepted it as a duplicate, so either they forgot to mention that condition, or they found it close enough to solve their problem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, $a_n>0$ is essential to the problem. See my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n^{2}=\frac {(a_na_{n+1})(a_na_{n+2})} {a_{n+1}a_{n+2}} \to 1$. So $|a_n| \to 1$ I will let you check that $a_n$'s have the same sign after some stage so $a_n \to 1$ or $a_n \to -1$